# Bootstrap Dropdown Background Styling Difficulty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to remove the greyish background color that occurs on the dropdown link on hover and click of it. It also appears on the Dropdown link when you hover over its dropdown menu items. Please see my unsuccessful attempt at taking care of this in my css (after the snippet).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.nav > li > a.link').click(function(e) { /*create selector that selects against dropdown toggle, when */
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('ul.nav > li > a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('ul.nav > li > a.dropdown-toggle').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  /* navbar */
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  }
  /* caret */
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:before {
    background-color: #000000;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:before,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus:before {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active:before {
    background-color: #ee3124;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a.active {
    color: #ee3124;
  }
  /*visibility of submenu on dropdown during hover over dropdown*/
  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /*background color of dropdown during nothng, hover, and open toggle*/
  .dropdown {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    transition: all 1000ms ease;
  }
  .dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .dropdown.open {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  /*links always remain bold no matter what, i.e. hover, focus, active,nothing*/
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  /* MY ATTEMPT AT CHANGING DROPDOWN BACKGROUND COLOR ON HOVER AND CLICK*/
  .dropdown-menu > li a:hover,
  .dropdown-menu > li a:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="okfb-logo.svg" width="70%" height="70%" id="logo">
          <img src="okfb-logo.png" />
          <!-- fallback with png image for browsers with NO SVG support -->
        </object>

      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
/* MY ATTEMPT AT CHANGING DROPDOWN BACKGROUND COLOR ON HOVER AND CLICK*/
.dropdown-menu > li a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li a:focus { 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    background-image: none; 
    filter: none; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are updating background-color for wrong selector.

to change the background color for dropdown links on hover and on focus

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover 
{
 color: #262626;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:transparent;/*or any color you want*/
}
```

To  remove grey shadow from dropdown, remove last two lines from **.dropdown-menu**.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175); //
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
```

and update it like this.

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Hope this helps you. Do comeback if still any issue.!

Comment: thank you for answering. this still isn't working. when I hover over the dropdown menu items, the grey background is still present.

Comment: Then try this .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu> li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: transparent;
} or use !important after the property to force it.